# Uniform convergence of this series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let us consider : $f_n : \mathbb{R}\ni x \mapsto \frac{x}{(x^2+n^2)\log(n)}\in\mathbb{R}$ for $n> 1$.

I need to prove that $\sum _{n\ge 0}f_n$ is uniformly convergent.
I've already proved that it is not normally convergent by studying the term $(f_n)'$.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: @Dzoooks Indeed it's $n>1$, my mistake. Your hint seems to be linked with normal convergence of the series ?

Comment: Indeed, [uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence) basically means it is independent of $x$.

Comment: @Dzoooks Ok I know what you meant ! It depends on the references, but some people use two notions : "uniform convergence" and "normal convergence" and the second one implies the first. And the goal of the exercise is to prove that there is only uniform convergence with no normal convergence.

Comment: @Dzoooks your inequality isn't true. Take $x=n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will use Cauchy's test. Let us consider
$$
\Big|\sum_{k=n+1}^m f_k(x)\Big|=\sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{|x|}{(x^2+k^2)\log k}
$$ for $m>n$. We can see that
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{|x|}{(x^2+k^2)\log k}&\le& \frac{1}{\log n}\sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{|x|}{x^2+k^2}\\
&\le&\frac{1}{\log n}\int_n^m \frac{|x|}{x^2+y^2}dy\\
&=&\frac{1}{\log n}\int_{\frac{n}{|x|}}^{\frac{m}{|x|}} \frac{1}{1+z^2}dz\\
&\le&\frac{1}{\log n}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+z^2}dz\\
&=&\frac{\pi}{2\log n}
\end{eqnarray}$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, we have
$$
\lim_{n,m\to\infty}\Big\|\sum_{k=n+1}^m f_k\Big\|_\infty \le\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{2\log n}=0
$$ and Cauchy's test gives the result.

Comment: Thank you but my mistake, it's the "series" not the "sequence" of functions. And with your argument it proves that this series is not normal convergent !

Comment: @Maman I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you but can you justify the inequality : $\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{m} \frac{\mid x \mid}{x^2 +k^2}\le \int \limits_{n}^{m} \frac{\mid x \mid}{x^2+y^2}\mathrm{d}y$ ?

Comment: @Maman It is derived from$$
\frac{1}{x^2+k^2}= \int_{k-1}^k \frac{1}{x^2+k^2}dy\le \int_{k-1}^k \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}dy.$$
Compare the area below the graph of $y\mapsto \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: Indeed very nice !